# java clone deep copy HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, clone

In my webapplication, I've to bring the same data from DB into the webapplicatio, which takes lots of time.
What I did is, that I took the data and put it into the HashMap. That way I dont't have to bring it every time into the webapplication. But the big problem is, that all user will operate on the same data, which they change. 
My first question is: Is it correct, to save the data brought from DB in a HashMap, so I don't have to query it from DB every time?
My second question is, in case I can use a HashMap to save the data,   I've to make a deep copy or clone of the data brought and put in the HashMap, so each user have a copy of the origin data. right?

The Object I've to clone is, a transfer object, which has references to other Object and HashMaps.
The process is so: bring first the data from DB, make classes and put all classes into a transfer object and put that transfer object into a hashmap. next time, bring the data from hashmap.

Thanks for every help.
Edit: That data coming from DB creates a online form and has default values like name and address and sex... All user have to edit the form for their own purposes. Thats way every user must have his own copy to operate on it.

Comment: Yes, you can do this, and no you don't need to make a deep copy. I don't know of any database caching solutions which use deep copies by default.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your response. I  don't want a database caching solution. I've somehow to clone the transfer object, so each user can use his own copy.

Comment: Or you can mandate or enforce that user's cannot change the object.

Comment: That data coming from DB is a online form with some default values, like name and address... Every user must change it according to his needs. Thats way it must be editable. And if one user change it, the other user should not see the changes of the first user. Thats way I've to make a copy for every user.

Answer (score 4):

A very simple way to deep clone is to serialize / deserialize the object. This will ONLY work if all keys / values in your hashmap implement `java.io.Serializable`.

eg:

```
public <T extends Serializable> T deepClone(T o) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);
    out.writeObject(o);
    out.flush();
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOut.toByteArray());
    return o.getClass().cast(in.readObject());
}
```

Comment: Hi Lance, thanks! I've some frameworks (commons-lang SerializationUtils,Java Deep Cloning LibraryDozer, and Kryo). some use serialization and some use reflection doing the deep clone. I've somehow to copy the transfer object but I'm glad to see that in the end I've to clone. THanks